# Can we reduce the column size and wrap the text in excel 2007 output of cognos report

Tags: javascript, excel-2007, cognos-10, cognos-bi

Is there any way in cognos report studio where we can shrink the column width when the report runs in excel output. The column is really wide in excel output.
Is there any way we can use javascript to reduce the column width in excel. The output looks fine in HTML ad PDF, but I want the report in excel 2007 format.

Comment: Is the data itself too wide, or is the column heading too wide?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way you can set the field width for an Excel Report from within Cognos. Maybe there are some Framework Manager settings that deal with how data is Exported as Excel?

Typically once the report is in Excel the end user can format it they way they wish. You could consider setting the fields in Excel to have wrap text enabled.

Also if you don't need detailed formatting, you could try the output in Excel 2007 Data format.

If the data is the last column, you could try moving it to have a column after it. That way in Excel the column might not Autofit to the proper width and you would only see parts of it.